# Append csv file to existing excel as new sheet

Tags: powershell

Below is the csv data I have

```
Index
-----
10.01.01.01
10.02.02.02
10.03.03.03
```

Tried like below and it is working fine

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\Scripts\Index.csv" | Export-Excel -Path "C:\Scripts\IPReports\ipaddress.xlsx" -WorkSheetname 'Index'
```

But the sheet is getting added at the end.I want to add this as first tab

**Note:
I don't have excel installed in server. using Importexcel to generate excel file**

Please let me know how to do this

Comment: Please show us your code that isn't working so we can help you. Stack overflow is not a code writing service :)

Comment: What code have you tried to get this done? You need to show a [mcve] of what you have tried, otherwise this is considered "asking for code" and is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you are a beginner and don't know where to start, take a look at the `ImportExcel` PowerShell module. For many tables and spreadsheets this module will be easier to work with than the `Excel.Application` COM object.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\Scripts\Index.csv" | Export-Excel -Path "C:\Scripts\IPReports\ipaddress.xlsx" -WorkSheetname 'Index' -MoveToStart
```

Thanks all